# How to NOT delete a file in a Azure FTP connector action if the transfer fails in a logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a successful connection setup between a FTP site and dropbox using a azure logic app.  But while setting it up it kept just downloading the file then, since I had the next step wrong, deleting.

In a test environment this is annoying.  In production, pretty awful.

Here is the code I am using on the action part:

```
 "operation": "UploadFile",
            "parameters": {
                "FilePath": "@{triggers().outputs.body.FilePath}",
                "content": {
                    "Content": "@{triggers().outputs.body.Content}",
                    "ContentTransferEncoding": "None"
                },
                "overwrite": true
            },
```

Is there anything I can do so that if it fails it leave the file on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but I will give it a try. Maybe you can reformulate the question if I misinterpret you.

But yes, there exists "conditions" in Logic Apps which can be used. If you are new to Logic Apps I'd suggest you use "designer view" and you can then click "Add condition to be met". This would visualize a text box in which you can formulate conditions. For instance:

```
@equals({your data}, bool('true'))
```

To check if some value is true, or something similar to check if data is null.

Comment: perhaps...let me play around with that and I will update this...thank you.